# Eclipse 2019-06 egit freeze ide

Tags: eclipse, egit, eclipse-2019-06

After updating to new version of Eclipse, I have problem. If I open a project that includes a .git file, the IDE freezes. If I open Window > Preference > Team > Git > Configuration, the IDE freezes.

To continue to work with Eclipse, I must uninstall the EGit plugin or disable "automatically share projects located in git repository" in Window > Preference > Team > Git > Projects.

I tried removing Eclipse and reinstalling the 2019-06 version of Eclipse but I have the same problem

I tried running Eclipse with the -consoleLog option so I have a log but I have no error when the IDE freezes.

I'm on CentOS 7 64-bit

Comment: You could try enabling monitoring in 'General > UI Responsiveness Monitor' to see what it reports. Also look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory.

Comment: i enable UI Responsiveness Monitor and i have error in log file
i can share this :
https://nopaste.xyz/?87f5219095a88476#pPYbSXRUOtJra+GXuq1ZIKlkYn64Ha57t+uNN9Imec4=

but i don't understand the problem,i use bad version of jdk ?

Comment: Probably Eclipse bug [548188](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=548188)